# Open source Time objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Are there any open source Time objects for Objective-C/iOS? 
I am making an app based on time and I have started to roll out my own Time object but I keep thinking that for something as simple as this there should be someone out there who has done this already?

I have searched on Google and Github but a lot of things have the word time so I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I know how to use NSDate, NSDateFormatters, and NSCalender to find the time, I'm just wondering if there is something out there to make my life easier.

This is what I have started to implement (I know how to implement it, just feeling like I am wasting my time reinventing the wheel).

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger second;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger minute;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger hour;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger seconds;

+ (Time *)timeWithSeconds:(NSInteger)seconds;
+ (Time *)timeWithDate:(NSDate *)date;
+ (Time *)timeFromString:(NSString *)string;
+ (Time *)currentTime;
- (Time *)subtractTime:(Time *)time;
```

Along with a readable description for 12 and 24 hour time

Comment: You haven't actually described the problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nsdate

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what I am looking for

Comment: Why don't you want to use `NSDate` (even if you wanted to build a `Time` wrapper around it?

Comment: I plan on using NSDate, I guess what I'm looking for is a Time wrapper on NSDate

Comment: The API you describe doesn’t make a lot of sense. Do yourself a favor and don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use `NSDate` to represent a point in time and `NSDateComponents` to represent partial dates or time intervals. Getting from now to the same time on the next day is more complicated than adding 86400 (=24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds) seconds to the current timestamp. These things are *really* hard, so use Apples code that already gets this right. Even with that it's easy enough to get things wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Combined with NSDate, NSDateFormatter and NSCalendar, it should give you most of what you want.

Comment: I have already looked at those. I am just wondering if someone has done this already.

Comment: You could also use the Core Foundation counterparts which ARE open source.